# There is a way to change Google Chrome icon on status bar?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, statusbar

I'm running Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 and I noticed that there is a Google Chrome icon on my status bar - I think is because of the background apps. There is a way to change the icon to monochrome?

If I could change the icon of the chrome notification would be great too.

[image]

Comment: Are you on the stable channel or the beta/dev channel? I thought the background notification is with Aura.

Comment: I'm with Chrome Unstable, I think that is aura.

Comment: That would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can find the original ico and change it to a monochrome.

```
sudo find / -name "*google*.ico"
```

Now you should know where is the icon and you can just change the file.

Comment: Assuming it hasn't been compiled into the binary. Also, the search can probably be reduced into the `opt` folder, since IIRC Google Chrome is installed in `/opt/google-chrome/` or somewhere around there.

Comment: Yep, it should be faster indeed.